# Core Data one to many insert multiple objects related to one

Tags: ios, core-data

In fact, I 'm trying to understand this process my model idea is like this

please check this picture

Table graph of Core Date 
http://im63.gulfup.com/WqlEfW.png

as you can see , i have Book and writer and the relation from writer to book is to many , i want to do

insert for example 10 books for one write at one time i have done this code

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    id delegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext * context =[delegate managedObjectContext];

    Writer * writerClass =(Writer *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Writer" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    writerClass.fullName=self.firstName.text;
    writerClass.website=self.website.text;

    Book* booksClass =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    booksClass.title =self.booktitle.text;
    booksClass.redate=self.redate.text;

    NSError * error =nil;

    if(![context save:&error]){

        NSLog(@"there was Error ");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"All Objects Added ");
    }

}
```

but that code will insert one book and one writer each time , i need explain and update to my code as following

for example i have this information

**writer** :

- fullName : James
- website  : google.com

**Books**

- title  : c++
  redate : 1/1/2013
- title  : computer A+
  redate : 12/3/2013
- title  : vb.net
  redate : 3/10/2013

All that books related to James . how i can insert all this information one time ?

Comment: did u check this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069211/core-data-insert-multiple-objects

Comment: Yes . but not what i need . please read my question .